# Single Sign On with ASP.NET MVC 5 Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on

I'm trying to create SSO for ASP.NET MVC5 projects. Scenario is: I want ProjectA to be used for authentication and provisioning different features to other site & ProjectB which allows users to perform their tasks. So users should be able to sign-in into ProjectA and should work with ProjectA or ProjectB without signing again. I followed this [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27576/Single-Sign-on-in-ASP-NET-and-Other-Platforms) article. However I'm not sure about how to implement it in ASP.NET MVC projects which use new Identity system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've done that using the [Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2)  check it out

Comment: Thanks Moes for reply. However, rather than Thinktecture, I decided to go ahead with Azure AD SSO.

Comment: Is it free? @MayurTendulkar